# Testing Microphone Linux command or python

Tags: python, linux, microphone

I think this question might has been asked. But I can find it.

My question is: I want to write a small program in python to run on Linux to record the user's voice with a record button. But I want to check if the microphone is detected than the record button is enable otherwise it will be disable.

I have been looking around in google, but most of them are talking about checking it with command line for a USB mike, but what I want is to check the mike that plugged into the microphone port not the USB. And some others are talking about using command arecord to record the voice to wav file then play it back. But I don't want to use this method. I want to check it before I let the user proceed of recording.

Please help.

Comment: I have been working with a lot of audio tools, but none of them checks whether a mic is connected or not. If one is there you record your signal otherwise just silence.

Answer (score 0):

If just a simple script then wrap arecord with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Or if need something more robust try [pyalsaaudio](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/pyalsaaudio.html)

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question.